# What does Set<TEntity> do in IDbSet interface?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I read an article about `UOW` in `Entity Framework`, it has some code like this:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

i really dont understand what does `Set<TEntity>()`do ?

Comment: `Set` is the method name and `<TEntity>` defines a [generic parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

Comment: Whast does 'set' do? can you give me some useful link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All entities are stored in a context with different flags (for example DELETED, CHANGED) in front of your database. If SaveChanges will be called a synchronization with the database will be triggered. The Set contains all deleted and modified marked entities/database records inside a transaction. If the transaction commit was successful the changes in all entities contained in the set will be visible; if not a rollback will be started. It acts like a cache tracking all changes inside the target transaction.
In this article a description of the UOW design pattern can be found (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern).